# OpenGL Lighting on a polygon

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I'm writing a very small game, in this game the player is carrying a flashlight.

The world the game takes place in is a small house.

The problem is that my walls are made by drawing polygons, one polygon is one wall. So when I shine my light on the wall it won't light up, only when the light hits one of the vertices do I see some light and only that one vertex gets lit up.

Is there any way to make the middle of this polygon affected by light even if there's no defined vertex there?

I also tested this with a positional light, and that also only affects the vertices.

Comment: Didn't you forget to calculate normals?

Comment: Yes, I've calculated the normals. The lights work fine when I'm using a normal positional light, not a spotlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is [Gouraud shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading), or just *per vertex* lighting. This is what the fixed function pipleline of OpenGL implements. However, nobody is using that in this millenium. What you ask for is [Phong shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading), or *per pixel*/*per fragment* lighting. In OpenGL, this means you have to use the *programmable pipeline* and have to write your own shaders. But you should be doing that anyway, as the fixed function pipeline is declared deprecated since GL3, and actually *removed* from modern core profiles of OpenGL.

So what I suggest you should do is learning modern OpenGL, maybe by follwoing some tutorials:

- [arcsynthesis](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)
- [open.gl](http://open.gl/)

The first one also cover lighting topics in general and per fragment lighting ([e.g. here](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut10%20Fragment%20Lighting.html)), but you should be aware that these are a bit more advanced topics, and it will take some time for a beginnger to learn all the basics first.

Comment: Since I'm doing this as an assignment for school I'm kind of forced to work with the fixed pipeline. I'm guessing the only option with the fixed pipeline is making my walls out of multiple polygons that form one complete wall?

But thanks for the explanation, I'll definately look into Phong shading when I'm allowed to use programmable pipeline so I'll keep these links for future reference.

Comment: @crognar: Well, that's the best you can do then.

Comment: @crognar: There are texture/register combiners, which will allow you to implement per-pixel shading without using shaders (they are basically the pre-cursor to pixel shaders from the stone age of GL). However, to be honest, learning how to use them would take more time than learning to use shaders. Otherwise, to get the kind of results you want using Blinn-Phong, you have to significantly increase your polygon (vertex) count.

Comment: @crognar This was many years ago, but since the fixed pipeline colors vertexes instead of pixels, increasing the number of vertexes also increases the smoothness of the lighting. 'Grid filling' solid walls would allow more variation on the lighting, but at a huge cost.